# Want to save email and password into json for automation testing on register form

Tags: java, json

```
I have the following code :
public class RegisterFormPage {
    public WebDriver driver;
    public WebDriverWait wait;
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();


    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
    long millisecondsDate = date.getTimeInMillis();
    String uniqueID = Long.toString(millisecondsDate);

    public RegisterFormPage( WebDriver driver ){
        this.driver = driver;
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    @FindBy(xpath = "//div[@id='account-register']")
    public WebElement checkRegisterFormPage;


    //region Personal details
    @FindBy (id="input-firstname")
    public WebElement firstNameField;

    @FindBy(id = "input-lastname")
    public WebElement lastNameField;

    @FindBy(id = "input-email")
    public WebElement emailField;

    @FindBy(id = "input-telephone")
    public WebElement phoneField;

    @FindBy(id = "input-password")
    public WebElement passwordField;

    @FindBy(id = "input-confirm")
    public WebElement confirmPassField;
    //endregion

    @FindBy(xpath = "//label[@class='radio-inline']//input[@value='1']")
    public WebElement newsLetterYes;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@value='0']")
    public WebElement newsLetterNo;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//div[@class='pull-right']//input[@value='1']")
    public WebElement termsCondcCheckBox;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@value='Continue']")
    public WebElement submitRegistrationBtn;

    public void saveToJson(String email, String password){
        try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter("src\\main\\resources\\data\\UserCredentials\\userCredentials.json", true)){
            obj.put("Email", email);
            obj.put("Password", password);
            file.write(obj.toJSONString());

        }
        catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void checkRegisterFormPageIsDisplayed(){
        Assert.assertTrue(checkRegisterFormPage.isDisplayed());
    }

    public void fillRegisterForm(String firstName, String lastName, String email,String phoneNo, String password){
        email= email + uniqueID.substring(5) +"@test.com";
        password = password + uniqueID.substring(5);
        firstNameField.clear();
        firstNameField.sendKeys(firstName);
        lastNameField.clear();
        lastNameField.sendKeys(lastName);
        emailField.clear();
        emailField.sendKeys(email);
        phoneField.clear();
        phoneField.sendKeys(phoneNo);
        passwordField.clear();
        passwordField.sendKeys(password);
        confirmPassField.clear();
        confirmPassField.sendKeys(password);
        saveToJson(email, password);
    }
```

When I run a test for this form, I am writing the email and password to json, but it is appending another json object. I want to write new values in the same json object. this is the result after running the test two times:
{"Email":"test13100626@test.com","Password":"pass13100626"}{"Email":"test13133828@test.com","Password":"pass13133828"}

Comment: Offtopic but please don't store user passwords as plaintext.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `FileWriter("userCredentials.json", true)` the `true` means that it will append. Simply change `true` to `false` or remove that parameter completely and it should solve your problem.

[FileWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean)):

> Constructs a FileWriter object given a file name with a boolean
>   indicating whether or not to append the data written.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but changing to false it will simplly delete old data and write new one. How to keep old data as well?

Comment: Load the file into an object, change what you want to change and write it to the file. However I think using a database would be easier and safer for what you want to accomplish